CircularProgressIndicator shows too late, when time consuming code has finished
I am trying to show a progress indicator in some time consuming code but the screen is not refreshed while the code is running. After the code is finished it animates the indicator.
The solution is probably simple for an experienced android developer which I am not.
I created a minimum code application to show the problem
activity_main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Start"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
                android:id="@+id/cpi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progress="0"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:indicatorColor="#FF0000"
                app:indicatorSize="95dp"
                app:trackColor="#606060"
                app:trackCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:trackThickness="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="157dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="108dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

MainActivity.java:
package com.hennep.testcircularprogress;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int iProgress = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        final CircularProgressIndicator progress = findViewById(R.id.cpi);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true ) {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progress.setProgress(iProgress,true);
                        }
                    },100 );
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e ) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ) {
                iProgress = 0;
                //progress.setVisibility( CircularProgressIndicator.VISIBLE );
                button.setText("Calculating...");
                for( int k = 0; k < 192; k++ ) {
                    Thread.yield();
                    for( int fk = 1; fk <= 1000; fk *= 10 ) {
                        for( int j = 0; j < 192; j++ ) {
                            for( int fj = 1; fj <= 1000; fj *= 10 ) {
                                for( int i = 0; i < 192; i++ ) {
                                    for( int fi = 1; fi <= 1000; fi *= 10 ) {
                                        // Calculate E192 three resistor resistive divider here, not relevant for the test
                                        iProgress = k;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                button.setText("Start");
                //progress.setVisibility( CircularProgressIndicator.GONE );
            }
        });        
    }
}

Also the text on the button does not change, I expect that to be the same problem.

How many time takes long until your for loop be completed ?! Is it a long time processing?

Long enough to think that you didn't touch the button (more than a few seconds). At least millions of iterations.

You are running the calculation on the main UI thread which causes the "stalled" UI behavior.  Button onClick handlers are executed on the UI thread.  Remember there is only one UI thread - so if it is busy doing calculations it can't refresh display.
Here are some improvements:
(1) First the UI progress update can be simplified to a self-arming runnable (which runs on the UI thread) to update the progress every 100MS.  NOTE: no sleeps.  And self-terminates when progress reaches 100.  It is started when the button is pressed.  It also updates the button with some feedback.
    Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);

    // The "new Handler()" is deprecated.
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            progress.setProgress(iProgress);
            if (iProgress < 100) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                b.setText(String.format("RUNNING: %d", iProgress));
            }
        }
    };

    // The handler progress updater is started when button is pressed (below)

(2) Use button processing to start a new thread (not on the UI thread by definition) to perform the calculation, update the progress and update the button as needed.
    b.setText("Start");

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b.setText("Running");
            b.setEnabled(false);

            iProgress = 0;
            // start the progress updater
            handler.postDelayed(r, 100);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long d = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    for (int k = 0; k <= 100; k++) {
                        for (int j = 1; j < 100_000_000; j++) {
                            // some calculation
                            double x = (double) d / j;
                        }
                        iProgress = k;
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            b.setText("Done - Restart");
                            b.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });

And result:


I couldn't start a second time. I had to add iProgress = 0; to the runOnUiThread->run. Now a second run works but a third time fails again.

@hennep Concerning the iProgress - likely was an earlier edit.   I too could not start it a third time; turns out the "fake" processing was being optimized away on subsequent runs - so I added something it couldn't ignore - see edit in run.  Now it can be restarted multiple times ( at least 5 anyways).  It actually was running the thread but the fake processing loop did not execute likely because optimization thought it already calculated nothing - a bit off-topic.

That last change did not work for me. The first two runs were much slower than the third and all runs after that. I on't know where that is coming from and I had to declare double x; outside OnCreate to make that go away. I also had to make it voltatile: volatile double x;
Maybe better change the text new Handler() is deprecated  in new Handler(/* without parameter*/). It put me on the wrong foot and made me start googling for an alternative :-)
